# Formatting Laravel JSON Object with relations

Tags: json, laravel, collections, models

My goal is to output JSON for an API like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "QUbkaUJhNm",
        "email": "w6KYFZnypT@gmail.com",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "profile": {
            "a": "value",
            "b": "value",
            "c": "value"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "lYXmtkKuX9",
        "email": "yu3dob2lyH@gmail.com",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "profile": {
            "a": "value",
            "b": "value",
            "c": "value"
        }
    }
]
```

I have two models.

The User Model:

```
public function profile() 
{
     return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

The Profile Model:

```
public function user() 
{
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

What should the code for my APIcontroller be?

```
$users = User::all();

...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Eager Loading like this:

```
return User::with('profile')->get();
```

if you want the result paginate

```
return User::with('profile')->paginate();
```

Comment: Now let's assume that `profile` has its own relations, how can I render them as well? Example: `User->profile()->phoneNumber()`